# Can't have more than one drop down for my menu because of position

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, css-position

This is my code, as you can see, I'm using position relative & absolute. Though using absolute means I cannot add more than one drop down without the drop down boxes being in the same space, I can't think of a solution.

```js
function opentabs() {
  window.document.getElementById('about').style.display = "block";
  window.document.getElementById('location').style.display = "block";
}

function closetabs() {
  window.document.getElementById('about').style.display = "none";
  window.document.getElementById('location').style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
#contact {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  color: white;
  font-family: corbel;
  border-color: white;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2x;
}

#about {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  color: white;
  font-family: corbel;
  border-color: white;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2x;
  display: none;
}

#location {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  color: white;
  font-family: corbel;
  border-color: white;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2x;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="contact">
  <p onmouseover="opentabs()" onmouseout="closetabs()" style="text-align: center;">Home</p>
</div>
<div id="about">
  <p style="text-align: center;">About</p>
</div>
<div id="location">
  <p style="text-align: center;">Location</p>
</div>
```

Comment: The 'standard' way of doing this is by having the elements that have to be shown on hover inside the element you have to hvoer on and then combine that with a simple css hover rule. So if you can describe what can be hovered and what should be shown... You usually don't wan't to use position absolute for menus, as resizing the browser might screw up the rest of you layout and will give you more issues when you try to nest more than one level deep.

Comment: Thank you for that, I'll try that.

Answer (score 0):

Example for my comment:

You'll have to play around a bit with the positioning, since you want height + padding + border + margin as the value for top on the submenu. Or alternatively use `box-sizing: border-box` and then use percentage values so you don't have to calculate fixed css values.
The trick is placing the submenu relative compared to the main menu button. This way the menu will stay in the same place compared to the main button, no matter where it's placed in the document.

The absolute positioning is useful for overlapping with other elements underneath the menu when combined with `z-index`.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
    .menu-btn {
        width: 100px;
        height: 50px;
        background-color: rgb(51,51,51);
        color: white;
        display: block;
        font-family: corbel;
        border-color: white;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 2x;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .menu-sub {
        display: none;
        position: relative;
        top: 54px;
    }
    .menu-main:hover > .menu-sub {
        display: block;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="menu-btn menu-main">Home
    <div class="menu-btn menu-sub">About</div>
    <div class="menu-btn menu-sub">Location</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

ps: you can fix your own code by just setting the left and top properties on your absolutely positioned elements. Location should be like 70 pixels to the bottom of Home, so that About can fit between them.

Something like

```
#about {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
} 
#location {
    position: absolute;
    top: 75px;
}
```

might already suffice to fix the issue of overlapping.